# hid usb gadget driver link to particular usb port

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to write Linux HID USB gadget driver on my linux machine. Since linux (**kernel version: 2.6.37**) already has completed HID gadget driver, I use it as a template. 
By referring the following websites:
**www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt**

Here are the Linux HID USB gadget driver code:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/2b9b0b6a95cb7adbdd4fa03bff2c7dec86852aa0/drivers/usb/gadget/hid.c

And this is my Linux machine USB subsystem block diagram
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNLx3.jpg)

By reading the instruction (**gadget_hid.txt**), I can successfully generate a kernel module. The problem is, my **USB port 0** has been used by other gadget driver, when trying to **insmod g_hid.ko**, the error message "device is busy" always prompts up. Unless I rmmod the gadget driver on **USB port 0** and insmod g_hid.ko, then my host can receive correct HID signal from **USB port 0**. My question is, can I possibly hook up this HID gadget driver to **USB port 1** only? Could anyone tell me, when USB connected, how the Linux machine deal with the gadget driver, on the **slave side**?

Thanks!